# Migrate project to new machine, application identity not set exception

Tags: vb.net

I have a VB.net application which was written using win7 64, visual studio 2017. I have migrated to a new machine using win 10, copied the project folder over, and opened.

I have made no other changes, and its a fresh install of visual studio 2017 on win10.

When I try and run the debugger, i get an exception thrown

> System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException: 'Application
>   identity is not set.'

when the debugger gets to the line

```
Label3.Text = "version " & ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion.ToString
```

This works when the application is published, but not in the debugger. The app is not network deployed, and I'm publishing using clickonce (build/publish wizard)

I've enabled 'just my code' in the debugging general options, but this makes no difference

I'm a beginner, so please speak in small words!

Comment: See [this MSDN link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.deployment.application.applicationdeployment.currentdeployment(v=vs.110).aspx) for explanation and a solution

Comment: thanks for replying, but I'm still not sure I understand. The application should be clickonce , but when I try and test using "If (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed) Then", it returns not network deployed. It was previously before the migration. I also have a similar problem if i create a clean forms application with nothing but a label showing CurrentVersion and publish to the local machine.